# swift:ARC: how to release all references to an UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have a ios/swift project where I place a lot of UIImageViews in an scrollview. I have multiple scrollviews and I want to make sure all memory is released when I close one. So far it seems like if I add an UIImage, it gets 16 references with the following code. If I run it on any device it runs out of memory and crashes.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    var backgroundView:UIImageView?
    var background:UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for i in 1 ..< 10000
        {
            print(i)
            scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))
            view.addSubview(scrollView!)

            if let backgroundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "jpg")
            {
                background = UIImage(contentsOfFile: backgroundPath)!
            }

            backgroundView = UIImageView(image: background)

            backgroundView?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 500, width: 500, height: 500)
            scrollView?.addSubview(backgroundView!)

            print(CFGetRetainCount(background!))
            print(CFGetRetainCount(backgroundView!))
            print(CFGetRetainCount(scrollView!))

            scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: view.frame.height)

            backgroundView = nil
            scrollView = nil
            background = nil
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get a reference count of zero to release the memory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 16 references? This code creates 9,999 scroll views (each time, leaving the previous one in the view hierarchy, but abandoning your reference to it upon the next iteration), each with their own copy of `1.jpg`, and each added as a subview of `view`. In terms of how to release the memory, you should remove any strong references you have, as well as remove any other references, such as the view hierarchy.

So, if you want to remove the references to the images, you can either reset the `image` property of the `UIImageView`, and/or remove the `UIImageView` (or the  `UIScrollView`) from the view hierarchy.

Note, your attempts to set `backgroundView` and `scrollView` to `nil` remove your strong reference to those, but called `addSubview` earlier, so the view hierarchy still has a strong reference to them. If you want to get rid of everything, before setting `scrollView` to `nil`, make sure to call `scrollView.removeFromSuperview()` in order to remove it from the view hierarchy.

Comment: i mean 16 references per UIImage. I was under the impression that setting the UIImageView, Scrollview and UIImage to nil would clear their references, but that does not seem to happen. I'll try to remove them from the view completely.

Comment: Setting those to `nil` remove your strong references to them, but when you called `addSubview`, you added them to the view hierarchy, which maintains its own strong references. You have to `removeFromSuperview` in order to remove it from the view hierarchy and resolve those last remaining strong references.

Comment: thanks, it took a while to implement in my actual project, but my problems are over! weight of my shoulders, close deadline :)